# Unable to run preinstalled Vim

Tags: vim

I had preinstalled vim but whenever I run it, it dosn't response.
I also had tried to reinstall it by removing via

```
sudo apt-get remove vim
sudo apt-get purge vim
```

and installed via

```
sudo apt-get install vim
```

but in vain

Comment: what command do you type to run?.

Comment: i just searched vim in all packages,, I found "run vim" that's it

Comment: **`vi`** is the original program **vim** is **vi IMproved**. usually, **vi** is pre-installed. try running `vi` instead.

Comment: still not worked